# PHP cannot access protected property error

Tags: php

I can't see anything wrong with this, but I see the above exception occasionally in the logs. What's wrong?

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access protected property Exception::$message in /web/index.php on line 23

On line 23 I have,

```
echo '<?xml version=\'1.0\'?><error-response status="error">
<message><![CDATA['.$e->message.']]></message>
</error-response>';
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Use `$e->getMessage()` instead of `$e->message` because message is a protected property :)

Comment: That worked perfectly in my TYPO3 Extbase project, except I used `$this->user->getUsergroup()`. The getter-setter principle - I start to get it.

Comment: Annoyingly using `$e->getMessage()` on my exception results in an error about calling an undefined function from my try catch block :/

Answer (score 23):

`$message` is a [protected](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) member of class Exception, as the error message states. You want the public accessor [getMessage](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.getmessage.php):

```
$e->getMessage()
```

Answer (score 6):

Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes.

```
class MyClass {
    public $public = 'Public';
    protected $protected = 'Protected';
    private $private = 'Private';

    function printHello()
    {
        echo $this->public;
        echo $this->protected;
        echo $this->private;
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
echo $obj->public; // Works
echo $obj->protected; // Fatal Error
echo $obj->private; // Fatal Error
$obj->printHello(); // Shows Public, Protected and Private
```

You can dig more into **Property Visibility** [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)