# "Cannot access protected property FacebookApiException ..."

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My cron for my application that post daily on user wall crashed today and i got the message error :

> "PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access protected property
>   FacebookApiException::$message in..."

That happened few minutes after I received a developer alert from facebook

> Your app appears to be requesting both read and write permissions at the same time. Instead, request a small number of permissions initially, and ask for write permissions when the user decides to share.
>   You can view this and other Developer Notifications related your app, *****, in the App Dashboard.

.

I cant resolve that problem. The alert in the facebook developer is empty and noted as resolved.

Any help?

Comment: I've got the same message from Facebook right now. Seems like it was planned to be sent for April 1st but due to an internal bug, we've just received it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Facebook engineer answered this question here.
https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/534303256613193/

Emil Hesslow said "The alert went out by mistake and we are working on cleaning it up. You can ignore it."

"But for now you can ignore the alert. If and when we changes it then it will be a breaking change just like other breaking changes."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The two things have nothing to do with each other. The `Cannot access protected property` is a [common error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307107/php-cannot-acess-protected-property-error) in object oriented programming when accessing a [private or protected field](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) of an object.

Answer (score 0):

I was work on facebook integration on http://harganews.com/

And I have found this kind of errors I also search "facebookApiException why protected" on google, but no one has the right answer.

Basicly facebook was protect this error code and all results, but you cannot access this directly.

You will able to access this by using getResult() function, like example below:

```
try{
    $status = 1;
    $photo = $this->facebook->api($fanpage_id . '/photos', 'post', $content);
}catch(CurlException $e){
    $status = 0;
    $photo = $e;
}catch(FacebookApiException $e){
    $status = 0;
    $photo = $e->getResult();
}
```

This works like a charm!