# if "message" is protected, how do I retrieve SOAP response called "message"?

Tags: php, soap

I'm really stuck on this one.  At the bottom of this post, I've attached the API documentation I'm working with.  I want to catch the "message" when the response ("ask") isn't "Success".  Seems reasonable enough, right?  But when I do something like:

```
sfcSendError('Something went wrong. This is the message from the API: ' . $result->message);
```

I get a fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Cannot access protected property SoapFault::$message
```

I found [this seemingly related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307107/php-cannot-acess-protected-property-error), so I tried changing "message" to "getMessage()" but (no surprise) that results in a different fatal error about calling an undefined function.

Here's my code snippet:

```
    $client = mySoapClient(MODULE_SHIPPING_SFC_API_URL);
    if (!$client) {
        sfcSendError('could not make a SOAP connection. Halting until next CRON. [' . __FILE__ . ':' . __LINE__ . ']', 'SOAP Failure in cron job');
        exit; //halt and wait for the next time cron runs
    } else {
        $HeaderRequest = array(
                        'customerId' => MODULE_SHIPPING_SFC_ACCOUNT,
                        'appToken' => MODULE_SHIPPING_SFC_TOKEN,
                        'appKey' => MODULE_SHIPPING_SFC_KEY
        );

        $reg = array(
                    'HeaderRequest'  => $HeaderRequest,
                    'detailLevel' => 1,
                    'ordersCode' => $_query->fields['sfc_ordersCode']
        );
        $result = $client->getOrderByCode($reg);
        if ($result->ask != "Success") {
            sfcSendError('Something went wrong. This is the message from SFC:  ' . $result->message, 'SOAP Failure in cron job');
            $_query->MoveNext();
            continue;
        }
}
```

This is the referenced function:

```
function mySoapClient($url)
{
    try {
        $client = @new SoapClient($url, array(
            'trace' => 1,
            'exceptions' => 0,
            'encoding' => 'UTF-8'
        ));
    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $client;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Or is this a "bug" with the API where they really shouldn't be using "message" in their response?

[image]

Comment: Give a link to the class mySoapClient();

Comment: Or navigate in the class and search in which method you can find: `return $this->message;`